# Adding a unit label to a color gradient legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Lets say I have plotted some variables in a figure, and linked the color of the points on the plot to some other variable. This is easy to do in `ggplot2` and generates the following figure:

```
require(ggplot2)
miss <- sample(c(NA, 1:5), nrow(mtcars), rep = TRUE)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = miss) +
  scale_colour_gradient(na.value = "black")
```

[image]

However, I want the 'miss' legend to have units. Specifically I want those units to be watts meter^-2 hour^-1 (with appropriately formatted superscripts). What is the most straight forward way to add this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a vector containing the label text you desire, including any special plotmath expressions, then use `parse` to evaluate it into an expression that will be rendered properly in the plot. Then, in the plot code, set the desired breaks using the `breaks` argument, with the corresponding labels in the `labels` argument.

```
labs = parse(text=paste0(1:5, "~watts%.%meter^-2"))

qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = miss) +
  scale_colour_gradient(na.value = "black", breaks=1:5, labels=labs)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** You can put the units beside the legend, but you'll probably need to tweak it manually to get the placement right (though someone who understands the grob structure of a ggplot better than I do might be able to automate it). Also, even though I've turned off clipping, the legend grob will still cover the units annotation if it gets too close to the legend. I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
p1 = qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = miss) +
  scale_colour_gradient(na.value = "black") + 
  annotate(x=max(mtcars$mpg) + 0.25*diff(range(mtcars$mpg)), 
           y=mean(range(mtcars$wt)) - 0.1,
           label=lbl, geom="text", parse=TRUE, angle=-90, size=3.3) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=range(mtcars$mpg)) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,2,0.5,0.5), "lines"))

# Turn off clipping
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt$layout$clip <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make this a single label that is "watts * meter^-2", perhaps rotated 90 degrees and to the left of the color gradient bar?

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted it only above in the legend this would be the solution

```
require(ggplot2)
miss <- sample(c(NA, 1:5), nrow(mtcars), rep = TRUE)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = miss) +
scale_colour_gradient(na.value = "black", name = bquote('' ~W ~ m^-2~h^-1*''))
```

[image]